# unable to access CQLSH from .cmd locally on VM

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to connect with my Cassandra DB resides in a Windows VM but while executing the command `cqlsh` on Local command window. I am getting an exception:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})
```

I'm able to connect this cassandra cluster from my cloud platform 'Databricks' with it's public ip using Spark but on local system it is throwing the error.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Cassandra configs, Check on which ip address you've bind your rpc calls to ?

if it's not localhost/127.0.0.1 then specify on which interface's ip you've bind it to..

then connect with specifying ip address -

```
cqlsh <ip address for rpcs calls>
```